# Method of counting constants / Krull's principal ideal theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In his book "Commutative algebra with a view towards algebraic geometry", Eisenbud cryptically remarks that Krull's principal ideal theorem (on the maximum codimension of components the zero set of a single equation) had been known for some time in enumerative geometry as the method of "counting constants".

Does anyone know what is meant by this?